# Can the "?" symbol be used to cast types in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

I found a piece of code online where there is this line:

```
new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.EmailVerified, 
     user.EmailConfirmed ? "true" : "false",
     ClaimValueTypes.Boolean)
```

While the code works I'm not sure what does that specific line do. I know the "?" symbol is used to nullify Types, but can it be used to cast Types as well?

Comment: That's a ternary operator and is entirely different from the `?` the symbolizes a nullable value. This operator is only available for boolean values and the `?` signifies what to do if the boolean value is true. `:` means otherwise.

Comment: Reference: [conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not for casting. It is just the [conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator), an easy syntax to do an `if-else` code block. So if the expression before `?` returns true, it executes the first expression ( the one followed by `?`) and return the value and if the expression before `?` returns `false`, it returns the return value of the second expression (followed by `:`)

So in your case, If  the value of the expression `user.EmailConfirmed` is `true` the code will be same as

```
new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.EmailVerified,  "true" , ClaimValueTypes.Boolean)
```

else (if it is `false`)

```
new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.EmailVerified,  "false" , ClaimValueTypes.Boolean)
```

You can also call the `ToString()` method on the boolean value and then call `ToLower()` method to get `true` or `false` . If you ever want to try that, Here is how you do it

```
new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.EmailVerified, user.EmailConfirmed.ToString().ToLower(),
                                                                ClaimValueTypes.Boolean)
```

I would personally prefer the first approach ( conditional operator), but probably replace the magic strings with some constants